# Specify which activity to resume on if user exits and then returns to app

Tags: android, android-activity, exit, resume

Is there an easy way to resume an app on a different activity from which it exited? i.e. if user exits app (e.g. press device home button) on a certain activity, when app is resumed I would like to resume on a different activity.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Its possible, with some tricky part like, using flags and activity life cycles with maintained track of these flags to ensure you are exited from your application on any activity of you application.

Comment: I'm trying to imitate how your device contacts works, if user is say in midst of creating a contacts group and then exits, if they return to contacts it will take them back to initial group activity not where they exited. This is exactly the functionality I'm trying to create, sounds like it might not be as simple as I thought?

Comment: Ohh. Its a simple, either you have to check weather group is created or not on `onPause()` of particular activity, now you can navigate to initial group activity at when user again return to last activity like, `onResume()` or just finish() the last activity when user try to exit from application on mid of group creating.

Comment: @user370305 could you say explicitly how it can be possible? Because activity life cycle does not allow to resume activity once it's destroyed. It will be so helpful for others too if you write answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step process

1) On every activity implement the onPause and then store (probably in sharedPreferences) a string or constant indicating the activity they should start when returning.

2) When your app starts have it enter a chooser activity which checks the sharedPreferences value and opens that activity. Make sure to remove it from shared preferences if you don't want them to always start on the new activity.